# How to unzip and re-zip files into subdirectory with the same name as .zip file?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, baseline

**Summary**
I need to *"fix"* a batch of .zip files, all over the filesystem, by:

- replacing a " " (space) in their names with a "_", as well as in the names of their contents' files
- re-zip them back

Stuck at unzipping because "$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0")" throws errors.

**Longer desc.**
File hierarchy:

```
banners/
       |
       germany/
       |      |
       |      active/
       |      |     |
       |      |     300x250/
       |      |     |      |
       |      |     |      file.jpg
       |      |     |      AC2 xx.zip
       |      |     |
       |      |     600x228/
       |      |            |
       |      |            file.jpg
       |      |            AC4 xx.zip
       |      nautics/
       |
       |
       austria/
       |
       ...
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
~/banners/> find . -name "*" -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$(0// /_)"' {} \;
```

Here I got rid of all the spaces in all the filenames/directory names from `banners/` downwards.
`AC2 xx.zip` now looks like `AC2_xx.zip`

I now need to unzip these .zip files into a new subdir, at the same level as the .zip files themselves, named the same as these .zip files.

**Here is the command I tried:**

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip "$0" "$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0")"' {} \;
```

which gives me a bunch (full screen of) of errors like this one:

> ~>Archive:  ./sun&sea/dugi_otok/970x250/SS4_970x250.zip
>   ~>caution: filename not matched:  ./sun&sea/dugi_otok/970x250/SS4_970x250.zip

For the life of me I cannot figure this one out.

**Re-run remove spaces**
If I get this to work and the files are unzipped, the plan is to re-run the `mv` command from the top level directory `banners/` and again replace spaces with "_" again. This takes care of the .zip files' contents.

**Re-zip**
Finally, I need to re-zip these newly created subdirectories, named as the original .zip files and overwrite the existing .zip files (that were initially unzipped).

Basically re-zip this:

```
~> banners/germany/active/dugi_otok/300x250/AC2_xx/(newly unzipped contents)
```

into:

```
~> banners/germany/active/dugi_otok/300x250/AC2_xx.zip
```

I apologise for the confusion but I couldn't find a better way to explain this.

Comment: Why did you add the tag [baseline]?

Answer (score 0):

`basename` does not strip the extension so your:

```
"$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0")"
```

just recreates `$0`. Replace with:

```
"$(dirname "$0")/$(basename -s ".zip" "$0")"
```

the `-s` option to `basename` strips a suffix

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> I now need to unzip these .zip files into a new subdir, at the same
>   level as the .zip files themselves, named the same as these .zip
>   files.

The `unzip` option `-d` is suitable for this:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c 'unzip "$0" -d "${0%.zip}"' {} \;
```

With the command you tried the second argument of `unzip` was taken as the name of a file to extract from the zip file, and of course not found therein.